# SSIS execute process task error handling

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssis, ssis-2012

in a SSIS Package is an execute process task, which start a BAT file. The Bat File list the content of a sFTP directory to check for new files. From time to time the package fails. For this I want to log the failure and proceed.

[image]

I’ve created a failure control flow but if the process task fails ,but for some reason if the bat runs into an failure the full SSIS package fails instead handling the error. Deployed to the SSIS Catalogue, there error is the following message:

```
run remoteLSbat: Error: in Executing “D:\SSISrun\remote_LS.bat” “” at “”.
The process exit code was “1” while the exoected was “0”.
```

which settings do I need to get control flow continue on the failure path and continue instead of exit the package??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the task properties, you need to ensure the flags to fail the package on failure are set to false, and increase the maximum error count to 2 or more.

[image: Screenie]

I think it would be better to not use the failure constraint if possible and instead have the batch file *execution* always succeed, but the package splits the workflow based on the value returned.

Comment: How to catch the value returned?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I think that should be a separate question in order for someone to answer it.